# Recebimento do id de inicio de sessão

Tags: php

Estou usando a [API em PHP do PagSeguro](http://forum.pagseguro.uol.com.br/t/10203457/exemplo-de-checkout-transparente) para efetuar um checkout transparente. Estou com problemas quando troco de ambiente de testes (sandbox) para produção.

Abaixo o trecho de código

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "url/GetSessionId",
    type:"GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId(response);
```

**PHP**

```
public function getsessionid(){
    $checkout = new Checkout(false); // Se for false, esta no ambiente de produção
    $checkout->printSessionId();
}
```

Na classe Checkout (da api do PagSeguro) o método `printSessionId()`

```
public function printSessionId() {

    // Creating a http connection (CURL abstraction)
    $httpConnection = new HttpConnection();

    // Request to PagSeguro Session API using Credentials
    $httpConnection->post($this->pagSeguroData->getSessionURL(), $this->pagSeguroData->getCredentials());

    // Request OK getting the result
    if ($httpConnection->getStatus() === 200) {

        $data = $httpConnection->getResponse();

        $sessionId = $this->parseSessionIdFromXml($data);

        echo $sessionId;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("API Request Error: ".$httpConnection->getStatus());
    }
}
```

E na classe `PagSeguroData.class.php` os dados de produção estão assim: *(Esta sendo chamado os dados de produção, não os da sandbox. O email e o token estão corretos. O token foi gerado novamente no PagSeguro e atualizado)*

```
'credentials' => array(
    "email" => "email@domain.com.br",
    "token" => "00000000011111111112222222222"
),

'sessionURL' => "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/sessions",
'transactionsURL' => "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions",
'javascriptURL' => "https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js"
```

O erro que ocorre é o 403

[image: Erro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo um usuário do fórum de desenvolvedores do pagseguro no tópico de exemplo de checkout transparente, este erro ocorre devido você não ter permissão para realizar o checkout transparente em ambiente de produção, você deve entrar em contato no site do pagseguro informando que necessita do checkout.

Segue o link do tópico no fórum do pagseguro - http://forum.pagseguro.uol.com.br/t/10203457/exemplo-de-checkout-transparente

Answer (score 3):

Se vc está usando a API PHP... Estou fazendo assim (ainda estou fazendo...)

```
<?php
require_once ("PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php");

$credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();  
$IDsession = PagSeguroSessionService::getSession($credentials);
?>
```

Depois o processo todo (ajax):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('button[name=finalizar]').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            success : function(){

                //*******************************************//
                //***** Inicializando a sessão checkout *****//
                //*******************************************//
                PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId('<?php echo $IDsession; ?>');

                //***************************************//
                //***** Obtendo o hash do comprador *****//
                //***************************************//
                var hashComprador = PagSeguroDirectPayment.getSenderHash();

                //******************************************//
                //***** Obtendo os métodos de pagamento *****//
                //*******************************************//
                PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({ 
                    success: function(resposta) { 

                        //*******************//
                        //***** CARTÕES *****//
                        //*******************//
                        var cartoes = resposta.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options;
                        var ArrayCartoes = Object.keys(cartoes).map(function(cartao){
                            return {
                                codigo: cartoes[cartao].code,
                                nome: cartoes[cartao].displayName,
                                sigla: cartoes[cartao].name,
                                path: cartoes[cartao].images.SMALL.path,
                                status: cartoes[cartao].status
                            };
                            //Tenho em "ArrayCartoes" todos os cartões retornados do PagSeguro
                            //Por exemplo os dados do primeiro cartão:
                            //ArrayCartoes[0].codigo
                            //ArrayCartoes[0].nome
                            //ArrayCartoes[0].sigla
                            //ArrayCartoes[0].path
                            //ArrayCartoes[0].status
                            //*O mesmo vale para os outros métodos de pagamento.
                        });

                        //*******************//
                        //***** BOLETO *****//
                        //*******************//
                        var boletos = resposta.paymentMethods.BOLETO.options;
                        var ArrayBoletos = Object.keys(boletos).map(function(boleto){
                            return {
                                codigo: boletos[boleto].code,
                                nome: boletos[boleto].displayName,
                                sigla: boletos[boleto].name,
                                path: boletos[boleto].images.SMALL.path,
                                status: boletos[boleto].status
                            };
                        });

                        //*************************//
                        //***** DÉBITO ONLINE *****//
                        //*************************//
                        var debitOnline = resposta.paymentMethods.ONLINE_DEBIT.options;
                        var ArrayDebitOnline = Object.keys(debitOnline).map(function(debito){
                            return {
                                codigo: debitOnline[debito].code,
                                nome: debitOnline[debito].displayName,
                                sigla: debitOnline[debito].name,
                                path: debitOnline[debito].images.SMALL.path,
                                status: debitOnline[debito].status
                            };
                        });

                    },
                    error: function(resposta) { 
                        //tratamento do erro 
                    }, 
                    complete: function(resposta) { 
                        //tratamento comum para todas chamadas 
                    } 
                });

            },
            error: function(resposta) { 
                //tratamento do erro 
                console.log(resposta);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```